# На мульти сайте wordpress не работает JQuery script, который при скроле должен прибивать меню к верху

Tags: jquery, wordpress, wordpress-multisite

Есть такая проблема: Когда верстал сайт , этот скрипт работал

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $menu = $("#menu");
        $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(this).scrollTop() > 180 && $menu.hasClass("default") ){
              $menu.removeClass("default").addClass("fixed");
        } else if($(this).scrollTop() <= 180 && $menu.hasClass("fixed")) {
               $menu.removeClass("fixed").addClass("default");
         }
    });//scroll
 });
```

JQ был подключен

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

После того как перевел сайт на Wordpress скрипт перестал работать. Я использовал такое подключение

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_scripts' );
function my_jquery_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}
```

Но не помогло
P.S script расположен в footer

Comment: В каком файле находится сам скрипт? Где подключение этого файла?

Comment: @KAGG Design script находится в footer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Скрипты должнгы быть в отдельных файлах и подключаться через `wp_enqueue_script()` с зависимостью от `jquery`. Подробнее [здесь](https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_enqueue_script).

Сам jquery трогать не надо, в последней версии WordPress уже подключен jquery 3.5.1.

WordPress подключает jquery в noconflict mode, поэтому первая строчка должна выглядеть так:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

Таким образом:

1. Вынесите ваш скрипт в отдельный файл в папке темы. Назовите его, скажем, `assets/js/scroll.js`
2. Замените в нём первую строчку на указанную выше.
3. Запустите этот скрипт.

```
/**
 * Enqueue my scripts.
 */
function my_jquery_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'my-scroll',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/scroll.js',
        [ 'jquery' ],
        '1.0.0',
        true
    );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_scripts' );
```

Comment: получается этот код можно убрать? 
 add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_jquery_scripts' );
function my_jquery_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
}

Comment: Да, его нужно убрать. Вместо него - код в моём ответе.

Comment: Я сделал все как сказано, но результата нет может в header что то не так?

Comment: Я разобрался! спасибо вам большое.